# Saving logo to vector and printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, print-design

I am trying to make a logo for my caffe, so it has to be in a vector size so that it can be printed later.

My question is when i save it to .AI can they, in the printing company, open this file, or they have to have the special program for it?

Sorry if my spelling is off :)
I am using Adobe Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely. Even if the have no AI. See the default setting for your AI file is just a PDF that has additional data embedded. Even a person who does not work in print could most likely open your work on mostly any operating system. Hell, even your web browser most likely  knows how to do it (just drag and drop the AI file into browser window).

Anybody who has Adobe acrobat should be able to.

Answer (score 1):

You can export the image as a PDF, EPS or SVG if your printer doesn't have Illustrator. However most printers do have Illustrator - it's the industry standard vector software. Ultimately you should really ask your printers which format they would prefer.

> Formats supported for Saving
>
> - Adobe Illustrator (ai)
> - Illustrator eps (eps)
> - Illustrator Template (ait)
> - Adobe PDF (pdf)
> - FXG (fxg)
> - SVG Compressed (svgz)
> - SVG (svg)

Source: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/kb/supported-file-formats-illustrator.html